# Free usability testing software

Tags: video-recording, usability-testing

I'm looking to do some quick and relatively straight forward usability tests on my website with a few select users.

Are there any free programs that would allow me record the users as they perform actions in the browser? I.e. Record user using webcam as well as screen actions they perform.

I only need it for a day or two for a college project.

I'm using a windows vista machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/camstudio/

It's fine for what I'm looking for.

Would still be curious if there are more advance free programs out there specifically for usability testing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "ALLCapture" record tool. actually this is not a free program but as you mentioned that you want to use it only for 1-2 days, then you can use its trial version.
you can use this tool upto 30 days.

It's Features are:

1. Record all screen activity in real-time, even webinars or video conferences
2. Convert PowerPoint presentations to Flash videos
3. Easily edit the captured video and insert captions, notes, special effects, etc.
4. Record sound during the capture process or add it conveniently during playback.

You can download this from : http://www.balesio.com/allcapture/eng/download.php this page.

- If you want another tool for permanent usage then you can use "Jing"
  refer this : http://www.techsmith.com/jing.html

Answer (score 0):

1. `CrazyEgg` - a tool, based on clicks. It consists of 4 parts: Heatmap, Scrollmap,  Overlay report, Confetti (it provides a detailed information on each item components).
2. `ClickHeat` - an open-source tool for collecting real data on actual users - time and place of click on a page. This tool usage does not affect the server load level.
3. `Clixpy` - a tool which tracks the mouse movement, clicks, scrolling, and data input which are conducted by the website users. In order to record the user movements, it is necessary to add certain JavaScript on a page.
4. `ClickTale` - the fee-based service for tracking and recording the user behavior on the site. The tool promotes the serious bugs removal.